# How to use JSON between PHP and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have made an application requesting data to a PHP and javascript receives the data and displays it.
At first I did it by getting the data separated by ',' and it works fine, but I want to do it with JSON and this is where I have the problem.
I receive the data and try to decode them but it gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <in JSON at position 0
     At JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
     At XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange
```

In the received variable I have:

```
"<meta charset="utf-8"/>
↵  {"rastro":"entrada:inicio-inicio-comprobarPerfil-conectar-","mensaje":"si","usuario":"Invitado47","password":"","email":""} "
```

My code is:
**PHP**

```
$jsondata = array();
$jsondata["rastro"] = $rastro;
$jsondata["mensaje"] = $mensaje;
$jsondata["usuario"] = $usuario;
$jsondata["password"] = $password;
$jsondata["email"] = $email;


echo '' . json_encode($jsondata) . '';
```

**javascript**

```
var xmlhttp;

xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {

         var contenidosRecibidos = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

I have looked at google for many examples and it seems all very simple but there is no way it works.

Thank you for your help

Comment: If you get "<meta charset="utf-8"/>" in the received variable, does that look like JSON to you? Looks like HTML to me...

Comment: try to use an online parser to validate your JSON. And the problem you have you shouldn't get `<meta charset="utf-8"/>`

Comment: Could you add your full PHP code? It should not send the meta tag.

Comment: try this to clean the out put buffer <?php


   echo "hi";
   ob_clean();
   
    echo json_encode($jsondata);
 
?>

Comment: Thank you all.
You had reason and the problem was in the beginning of PHP, in the first line had:<meta charset="utf-8"/>

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best solution but this is what I use to use JSON in Javascript via PHP.

PHP:

```
    <script>
           var datavalue= <?php echo json_encode($answers) ?>; 
    </script>
```

The data is a JSON object. I also recommend to have a look at jQuery, which provides excellent ways to call PHP pages and have JSON as a result.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your PHP page is throwing some error/warning.
Try to print response like this.

```
    echo json_encode($jsondata);
```

That might not be the cause for your proble. But I strongly suspect that your PHP page is throwing some warning.
And are you sure `$password` is not "Undefined" ?
Try

```
    console.log(xmlhttp.responseText)
```

before parsing it. You'll get the warning/error.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. The problem was in the beginning of PHP, in the first line had:

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
```